# What is a proper way to check if StorageFile's ImageProperties has DateTaken property?

Tags: c#, windows-8, microsoft-metro, exif

I would like to know if a file has ImageProperties.DateTaken property.

Documentation says:

> If the date property isn't set, this value defaults to 0 which can be
>   translated into misleading dates in different programming language. In
>   JavaScript, for example, 0 translates to December 16, 1600. You should
>   always check that this property is a real value an not 0.

How should I do a check for "is date zero"? I've noticed that in C# if file doesn't have DateTaken property then DateTaken is 1st January 1601 (it's interesting that it's different from what docs say about "zero" date in JavaScript).

Is there a better way then to compare to 1/1/1601?